# What is the correct syntax for my for loop in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I've made a wpf program and have this for loop to get the name of the item, qty and prc's values and convert them to string to display them on the spreadsheet that I loaded within the application.

So far my working code is this:

```
worksheet1.Range["C14:D14:E14"].Value = got_item;
worksheet1.Cells["A14"].Value = qty.Value.ToString();
worksheet1.Cells["G14"].Value = prc.Value.ToString();
v1 = got_value;
i1q = Int32.Parse(qty.Value.ToString());
i1p = prc.Value;
```

However, I will have to repeat those for 12 more times until:

```
worksheet1.Range["C26:D26:E26"].Value = got_item;
worksheet1.Cells["A26"].Value = qty.Value.ToString();
worksheet1.Cells["G26"].Value = prc.Value.ToString();
v13 = got_value;
i13q = Int32.Parse(qty.Value.ToString());
i13p = prc.Value;
```

It's working good but it isn't very appealing to look at so I tried to create a for loop for it but I have little to no experience with for loops.

I tried my best and so far here is my progress:

```
for(x=0;x<13;x++)
{
    y += x + 13;
    worksheet1.Range["C"+y+":D"+y+":E"+y].Value = "";
    worksheet1.Cells["A"+y].Value = qty.Value.ToString();
    worksheet1.Cells["G"+y].Value = prc.Value.ToString();
    v + x = got_value;
    i + x + q = Int32.Parse(qty.Value.ToString());
    i + x + p = prc.Value;
}
```

I'm having troubles connecting the for loop values of x and y:

1. y to the worksheet range and cells
2. x to call the v(x), i(x)q and i(x)p

**UPDATE: Thanks to Jcl, here is my final result:**

```
for (x = 0; x < 13; x++)
{
    y = x + 14;
    y.ToString();
    b[x] = worksheet1.Range["C" + y + ":D" + y + ":E" + y].Value.ToString();

    if (b[x] == "")
        {
            worksheet1.Range["C" + y + ":D" + y + ":E" + y].Value = got_item;
            worksheet1.Cells["A" + y].Value = qty.Value.ToString();
            worksheet1.Cells["G" + y].Value = prc.Value.ToString();
            v[x] = got_value;
            iq[x] = Int32.Parse(qty.Value.ToString());
            ip[x] = prc.Value;
        }
}
```

Although this doesn't work off the bat since the if statement is getting looped without an else if, a simple solution would be to just create an individual if statement and loop the else if part for 12 times.

I'll try studying cases if it could be applied but nevertheless, thank you again Jcl. Just knocked off multiple lines of code and learned looping at the same time.

Comment: I was trying to enter the variable v + (x value) to produce a v1 = got_value like on my first code. same goes for i, p and q.

Comment: Note that your `y.ToString()` is not doing anything there. `ToString()` returns the converted value as an string, but you are not assigning it anywhere. For what is worth, you don't need it (since if using the integer `y` within a string with concatenation automatically uses `ToString()`), so you should remove that line alltogether.

Comment: Oh, I thought I had to convert it to be read as a string. Thank you, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of the problem is that here:

```
y += x + 13;
```

You are incrementing the value of `y` by `x+13`.

So in the first iteration, `y` is `0`, and `x` is `0`, you get `y=13`.
In the second iteration though, `y` is `13` and `x` is `1`. So you **increment** `y` by `1+13`, and end up with `y=27`.
In the third iteration, `y` is `27` and `x` is `2`, so you increment `27+(13+2)`, so `y=42`.
(etc.)

If in your first iteration, your `y` must be `13`, in the second iteration, must be `14`, etc., then you need to put it like:

```
y = x + 13;
```

Without the `+=`

The second part of the problem is that you can't just evaluate the result of an expression to a name of a variable (it can be done via reflection, but let's forget that).

So instead of having variables `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, etc, and `i1q`, `i2q`, etc., what make sense here is having some kind of array or list.

So wherever you are defining those variables, you should have something like (I can't figure out the types because the names you gave are not very descriptive, so I'll figure they are integers, change the type as appropiate):

```
int[] v = new int[14];
int[] iq = new int[14];
int[] ip = new int[14];
```

So when accessing those variables in the loop:

```
v[x] = got_value;
iq[x] = Int32.Parse(qty.Value.ToString());
ip[x] = prc.Value;
```

Note that arrays in c# are based on the index 0, but that's right, since your `for` loop, as currently stated, iterates from 0 to 12 (not from 1 to 13).

Comment: Thank you so much I finally finished it, sorry it took a long time to reply because after your solution, I wanted to also fix the spreadsheet syntax to have them all fixed.